# Slow performance trying to query mongodb with more than 30 million docs in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, document

I'm building an API to retrieve documents from mongodb, mongo has more than 30 million documents, it takes like 45-60 seconds using the below java code to query documents in this structure:

```
   {
    "Type": "CUS",
    "ID": "01010101",
    "Set": [
        {
            "Group": "Marketing",
            "Rule": "Rule_1",
            "Ind": "Y", 
        },
        {
            "GroupName": "Sales",
            "RuleName": "Rule_2",
            "Ind": "N",
        }
    ]
   }


    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

    query.put("ID", new BasicDBObject("$in", payload.getIds()));

    FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(query);

    for (Document doc : documents) {

        // looping through docs and then construct some objects and returns the result to the controller class

    }
```

it looks like it takes too much time on the loop part "for (Document doc : documents)", I'm not sure what's going on, can you please help.

Thanks, and I appreciate it.

Comment: For now the maximum number of ids "payload.getIds()" in the query is 200, not sure if this was the main problem!

Comment: Does the ID field have an index created for it? It looks like you created an ID field other than _id field, Am i correct?

Comment: yes, there is no index for the other ids I created

Comment: I just added an index on the ID and now I got a really fast performance. Thanks!